# Minus credit from debit column in same query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following Query:

SELECT user_id, SUM( credit ) AS cred, SUM( debit ) AS deb
FROM account
WHERE user_id =  '35'

I want to minus debit from credit and show it in one column or as a value in a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can calculate the difference in the same line

```
SELECT  user_id, 
        SUM(credit) AS cred, 
        SUM(debit) AS deb,
        SUM(credit) -  SUM(debit) total
FROM account 
WHERE user_id = 35
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  user_id, 
        SUM(credit) AS cred, 
        SUM(debit) AS deb,
        SUM(credit) -  SUM(debit) total
FROM account 
WHERE user_id IN (30,31,32,33,34,35)
GROUP BY user_ID
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
SELECT  user_id, 
        SUM(credit) AS cred, 
        SUM(debit) AS deb,
        SUM(credit) -  SUM(debit) total
FROM account 
WHERE user_id IN (30,31,32,33,34,35)
GROUP BY user_ID
HAVING (SUM(credit) -  SUM(debit)) < 10
```

Comment: what if I have different users id, so should I put like user_id = '30,31,32,33,34,35' etc......

Comment: @Akaash Then you can use `IN` with a `GROUP BY`. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks you all for your quick replies.. I just need now is to select only these users id where total is less than 10 from the pool of users id

Comment: what do you mean by `total is less than 10 from the pool of users id`?

Comment: like i have list of users, but i want only those users from that list those who have total less than 10, (minus debit from credit as total)

Answer (score 3):

This should work and is probably slightly faster than doing two other `SUM`s

```
SELECT a.user_id, 
       a.cred, 
       a.deb, 
       a.deb - a.cred AS value 
FROM   (SELECT user_id, 
               Sum(credit) AS cred, 
               Sum(debit)  AS deb 
        FROM   account 
        WHERE  user_id = '35') a
```

If you have multiple users, you can do something like:

```
SELECT a.user_id, 
       a.cred, 
       a.deb, 
       a.deb - a.cred AS value 
FROM   (SELECT user_id, 
               Sum(credit) AS cred, 
               Sum(debit)  AS deb 
        FROM   account 
        WHERE  user_id IN (35, 36, 39)
        GROUP BY user_id) a
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84da7/1)